# listing joined query with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I want to list my code.  I listed single query BUT the query i want to list is joined query.

```
app.get('/dormitory1', (req, res)=>{
    client.query(`Select * from dormitory1`, (err, result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.send(result.rows);
        }
    });
   
})
```

this is my get request, database code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import UpdateDormitory from './UpdateDormitory';

const ListDormitory = () => {
  const[dormitory1,setDormitory1]=useState([])

  const deletedormitory = async id => {
    try {
      const deletedormitory = await fetch(`http://localhost:2103/dormitory1/${id}`, {
        method: "DELETE"
      });

      setDormitory1(dormitory1.filter(dormitory1=> dormitory1.dormitoryid!== id));
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  const getDormitory = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:2103/dormitory1");
      const jsonData = await response.json();

      setDormitory1(jsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDormitory();
  }, []);

  console.log(dormitory1);


  return (
      <>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
  {" "}
      <table class="table mt-5 text-center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name of Dormitory</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Type of Dormitory</th>
            <th>Capacity</th>
            <th>Current Capacity</th>
            <th>Check In Time </th>
            <th>Check Out Time</th>
            <th>Number Of Meals</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {dormitory1.map(dormitory1 => (
            <tr key={dormitory1.dormitoryid}>
              <td>{dormitory1.nameofdormitory}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.locationid}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.typeofdormitory}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.capacity}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.currentcapacity}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.checkintime}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.checkouttime}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.numberofmeals}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.phone}</td>
             
              
              <td>
              <UpdateDormitory dormitory1={dormitory1} />
              </td>
              
              <td>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-danger"
                  onClick={() => deletedormitory(dormitory1.dormitoryid)}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </>
  )
}

export default ListDormitory
```

and this my listing code

they're working

they're picture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgCOd.png)

```
app.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { city,district,typeofdormitory} = req.query;
  
  
      const search = await client.query(
        `SELECT (dormitory1.nameofdormitory,
          location.city,
          location.district,
          dormitory1.typeofdormitory,
          dormitory1.capacity,
          dormitory1.checkintime,
          dormitory1.checkouttime,
          dormitory1.numberofmeals,
          dormitory1.phone
         ) FROM location
        inner join dormitory1 on location.locationid=dormitory1.locationid  
        WHERE (city ILIKE $1 and district ILIKE $2 and typeofdormitory ILIKE $3)`,
        [`%${city}%`,`%${district}%`,`%${typeofdormitory}%`]
      );
  
      
  
      res.json(search.rows);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  });
```

the query I want to list

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Search = () => {
    const[search,setSearch]=useState([]);
    const[dormitory1,setDormitory1]=useState([]);
    const[location,setLocation]=useState([]);

    const getSearch = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch("http://localhost:6302/search");
          const jsonData = await response.json();
    
          setSearch(jsonData);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getSearch();
      }, []);
    
      console.log(search);
    
  return (
    <>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
  {" "}
      <table class="table mt-5 text-center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            
            <th>City</th>
            <th>District</th>
            <th>Name of Dormitory</th>
            <th>Type of Dormitory</th>
            <th>Capacity</th>
            <th>Current Capacity</th>
            <th>Check In Time </th>
            <th>Check Out Time</th>
            <th>Number Of Meals</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
        {search.map(search => (
            <tr key={search.locationid}>
              <td>{search.city}</td>
              <td>{search.district}</td>
            
              
             
            </tr>
          ))}


          {/* {search.map(dormitory1 => (
            <tr key={dormitory1.dormitoryid}>
              <td>{dormitory1.nameofdormitory}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.typeofdormitory}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.capacity}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.checkintime}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.checkouttime}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.numberofmeals}</td>
              <td>{dormitory1.phone}</td>
             
             
            </tr>
          ))} */}
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </>
  )
}

export default Search
```

I wrote this code but it doesn't work
they're picture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27p8J.png)